# Simple picture app for storing and viewing

Tags: scala, mongodb, rest, nosql

**Update:** git repo: https://github.com/muhsinali/picture-example-minified

This is my first project that I've written using Scala and the Play framework. It's a simple application that allows the user to store pictures and see them (no edit/delete functionality, just to keep the code review simple).

I have included a couple of questions as `TODO`s in the source code (only 1 Scala file).

Please comment on how I could improve the readability and structure of the code.

**routes file:**

> ```
> GET     /                                   controllers.Application.index
> POST    /                                   controllers.Application.upload()
> GET     /get-picture-of-place/:name         controllers.Application.getPictureOfPlace(name: String)
> ```

**Application.scala (contains the model and controller):**

```
package controllers

import javax.inject.Inject

import com.google.common.io.Files
import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.data.Forms._
import play.api.mvc.{Action, Controller}
import play.modules.reactivemongo.{MongoController, ReactiveMongoApi, ReactiveMongoComponents}
import reactivemongo.api.ReadPreference
import reactivemongo.api.collections.bson.BSONCollection
import reactivemongo.bson.{BSONDocument, Macros}


//TODO how do I used DI instead of these two imports?
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.i18n.Messages.Implicits._

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}


case class PlaceData(name: String)

case class Place(name: String, picture: Array[Byte])

object Place {
  implicit val formatter = Macros.handler[Place]
}



class Application @Inject()(val reactiveMongoApi: ReactiveMongoApi)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends Controller
  with MongoController with ReactiveMongoComponents {

  def index = Action.async {implicit request =>
    retrieveAllPlaces.map(places => Ok(views.html.main(places, Application.createPlaceForm)))
  }

  def placesFuture: Future[BSONCollection] = database.map(_.collection[BSONCollection]("places"))

  def retrieveAllPlaces: Future[List[Place]] = {
    val placesList = placesFuture.flatMap({
      _.find(BSONDocument()).
        cursor[Place](ReadPreference.Primary).
        collect[List]()
    })
    placesList
  }

  // TODO would like to use an ID that's generated internally (find out how to use ObjectID from MongodDB database)
  def findByName(name: String): Future[Option[Place]] = {
    val foundPlace = placesFuture.flatMap({
      _.find(BSONDocument("name" -> name)).one[Place](ReadPreference.Primary)
    })
    foundPlace
  }

  def getPictureOfPlace(name: String) = Action.async{
    findByName(name).map(placeOpt =>
      if (placeOpt.isDefined) Ok(placeOpt.get.picture)
      else BadRequest(s"Could not retrieve the place named $name")
    )
  }

  def upload = Action.async(parse.multipartFormData) { implicit request =>
    val boundForm = Application.createPlaceForm.bindFromRequest()
    boundForm.fold(
     formWithErrors => {
       // TODO pass in formWithErrors into index method so that the form is populated with the values.
       Future(Redirect(routes.Application.index()).flashing("error" -> "Could not upload place. Please correct the form below."))
     },
      placeData => {
        placesFuture.flatMap(places => {
          request.body.file("picture").map { picture =>
            places.insert(Place(placeData.name, Files.toByteArray(picture.ref.file)))
            Future(Redirect(routes.Application.index()).flashing("success" -> "Successfully added place"))
          }.getOrElse {
            Future(Redirect(routes.Application.index()).flashing("error" -> "Could not upload place. Please correct the form below."))
          }
        })
    })
  }
}

object Application {
  val createPlaceForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "name" -> nonEmptyText
    )(PlaceData.apply)(PlaceData.unapply)
  )
}
```

**main.scala.html (the view):**

```
    @(placesList: List[Place], form: Form[PlaceData])(implicit flash: Flash, messages: Messages)

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Places</title>
</head>
<body class="container">
@if(flash.get("success").isDefined){
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        @flash.get("success")
    </div>
}

@if(flash.get("error").isDefined){
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        @flash.get("error")
    </div>
}

@helper.form(action = routes.Application.upload, 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data") {
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Add new place:</legend>
        @helper.inputText(form("name"))
        @helper.inputFile(form("picture"))
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Create</button>
    </fieldset>
}

@for(place <- placesList) {
    <p>@(place.name)</p>
    <img style="height:200px;" src="@routes.Application.getPictureOfPlace(place.name)" />
}
</body>
```

**conf/application.conf:**

```
play.crypto.secret = "changeme"
play.i18n.langs = ["en"]


# Enable ReactiveMongoModule
mongodb.uri = "mongodb://localhost/pictureMinifiedDemo"
play.modules.enabled += "play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoModule"
mongo-async-driver {
  akka {
    loglevel = WARNING
  }
}
```

**build.sbt:**

```
name := """pictureExampleMinified"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  ws,
  "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.11.14",
  "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "1.5.1" % Test
)
```

Comment: `def placesFuture: Future[BSONCollection]`  I am curious why this is a `def` instead of a `val` or maybe a `lazy val`.

Comment: @Thilo There's no particular reason. I felt that it needed to be a `def` to ensure that the latest collection is always used, so you don't miss out any updates made to the collection. Also, a `def` is used in the documentation here: http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/tutorial/database-and-collection.html. Would it be preferable to use a `val` here?

Comment: That is the part I am wondering about. If a `def` does anything useful (such as "ensuring that the latest collection is always used", or re-connecting if the connection failed), then it should be a `def`. But I don't think it does. It seems to always return an exactly equivalent collection object (does that do more than just contain the collection name?) based on the the same Future connection.  I am not 100% sure, though. We have the same case in our codebase, and I'd like some authority to speak on this.

Comment: Can you upload the project to a public git repository somewhere?

Comment: @Thilo done, see https://github.com/muhsinali/picture-example-minified

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. As it turns out that `database` in `database.map(_.collection[BSONCollection]` is also a `def`. I mistook it for a `val` because it is called without braces. And just like you say, it will return a fresh object in case the database connection was distributed and reconnected. There is also some logic in there to wait a certain time for the connection to become available.  So your `placesFuture` is correctly a `def` and you don't want to cache this object.

Comment: @Thilo great thanks for explaining! By the way, do you have any suggestions on how I could improve the code by any chance?